# Alarmmanager when app is updated

Tags: java, android

Im working on an app that uses `AlarmManager` for some processes. I wanted to ask that if i update my app on the playstore. (update not new install) will registered alarms get canceled? Also will values of `SharedPreference` get reset?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - Alarm lost after app update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088431/android-alarm-lost-after-app-update)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Alarms**: Yes, they will get canceled but you can restart your alarms.

Here is the solution from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/34464059/3474021

Have a broadcast receiver registered within your app with 2 intent filters namely:

1. `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) - called when your device restarts. Alarms are cancelled when device is shut down.
2. `android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED)) - called once your app is reinstalled or updated from play store or from any source.

You will also need the permission `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` to receive `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`. In this receiver you can start your alarms again.

**SharedPreferences**: No, they will remain when an app is updated.

Comment: Great! Thank You for your answer.

Comment: Do you have a reference documenting that alarms are in fact cleared when the app is updated? I don't see this mentioned in the AlarmManager docs, and when I install an updated version locally, the alarms are still present.

Comment: @hustoj2 I concur! Just did a test on API33 by capturing a before and after as it relates to catching ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED and all alarms were retained afterward!

Comment: With or without using the `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` solution: something strange that I noticed was that if, during development, the app is re-installed by running the app via Android Studio, previously scheduled alarms go away. However, if you use `adb` to install the APKs generated by Android Studio, the alarms don't go away.

Comment: @Bink yes all alarms will be there but it is not triggering.

Comment: @hustoj2 here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/alarms/schedule#boot) from Google official Docs that says "By default, all alarms are canceled when a device shuts down".